# Upload de Imagens com PHP + MySql

Tags: php, html, mysqli, upload, crud

Estou trabalhando em um projeto que requer o cadastro do funcionário com a imagem dele no formulário. Até ai tudo bem, está realizando normalmente o `insert`, tanto dos dados quanto da imagem. Mas quando tento realizar o `update`, a imagem vinculada(estou trabalhando com o banco em `varchar 255` e salvando o caminho da imagem na pasta `./fotos`) ela perde o vinculo com o `ID` referenciado inicialmente.

Já tentei inumeras possibilidades de códigos diferente, porém estou a 15 dias nisso e nao consigo sair! Alguem pode me ajudar?

Preciso somente realizar o `update` das informações e quando necessário realizar o `update` da imagem para atualiza-la no cadastro do funcionário.

```
HTML

    <?php
    session_start();
        if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
            $usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'][0];
            
            
        }else{
            echo "<script> window.location = 'index.php'</script>";
        }
?>
<?php
include_once('conexao.php');
$id = $_GET['id'];
 ?>
 <!--php-->


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Title Page-->
    <title>1º BPTran</title>

    <!-- Font special for pages-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Main CSS-->
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page-wrapper bg-dark p-t-100 p-b-50">
        <div class="wrapper wrapper--w900">
            <div class="card card-6">
                <div class="card-heading">
                    <h2 class="title">Atualizar Cadastro de Efetivo</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                
                
                <?php
                $rs = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tb_efetivo WHERE re=$id");;
        if($rs->execute()){
                if($rs->rowCount() > 0){
                    while($row = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
        
                    ?>
            
                
                    <form method="POST" action="update_efetivo_img.php">
<!-- DADOS PESSOAIS-->
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class=""><h2>Dados Pessoais</h2></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="name">Nome Completo</div>
                            <div class="value">
                                <input class="input--style-6" type="text" name="nome_completo" value="<?php echo $row->NOME_COMPLETO; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="name">Data de Nascimento</div>
                            <div class="value">
                                <input class="input--style-6" type="text" name="dt_nasc" value="<?php echo $row->DATA_NASCIMENTO; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="name">CPF</div>
                            <div class="value">
                                <input class="input--style-6" type="text" name="cpf" value="<?php echo $row->CPF; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="name">RG</div>
                            <div class="value">
                                <input class="input--style-6" type="text" name="rg" value="<?php echo $row->RG; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="name">CNH</div>
                            <div class="value">
                                <input class="input--style-6" type="text" name="cnh" value="<?php echo $row->CNH; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="name">Endereço</div>
                            <div class="value">
                                <input class="input--style-6" type="text" name="endereco" value="<?php echo $row->ENDERECO; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="name">Telefone</div>
                            <div class="value">
                                <input class="input--style-6" type="text" name="telefone" value="<?php echo $row->TELEFONE; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
<!-- DADOS FUNCIONAIS-->                        
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class=""><h2>Dados Funcionais</h2></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="name">Posto/Graduação</div>
                            <div class="value">
                                <input class="input--style-6" type="text" name="pg" value="<?php echo $row->P_G; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="name">RE</div>
                            <div class="value">
                                <input class="input--style-6" type="text" name="re" value="<?php echo $row->RE; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="name">Nome de Guerra</div>
                            <div class="value">
                                <input class="input--style-6" type="text" name="ng" value="<?php echo $row->QRA; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="name">Companhia</div>
                            <div class="value">
                                <input class="input--style-6" type="text" name="cia" value="<?php echo $row->CIA; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="name">Função</div>
                            <div class="value">
                                <input class="input--style-6" type="text" name="funcao" value="<?php echo $row->FUNCAO; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="name">Email Funcional</div>
                            <div class="value">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input class="input--style-6" type="email" name="email" placeholder="example@policiamilitar.sp.gov.br" value="<?php echo $row->EMAIL_FUNCIONAL; ?>">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="name">Observações</div>
                            <div class="value">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <textarea class="textarea--style-6" name="obs" placeholder="Digite as observações"><?php echo $row->OBS; ?></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="name">Foto de Identificação</div>
                            <div class="value">
                                <div class="input-group js-input-file">                                 
                                    <input type="file" name="foto" value="">
                                    <input class="input--style-6" type="text" name="foto" READONLY="true" value="<?php echo $row->FOTO; ?>">
                                    <img src='./fotos/'<?php echo $row->FOTO; ?>>
                                </div>
                                <div class="label--desc"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
        <?php }}} ?>
                        <div class="card-footer" align="center">
                    <input class="btn btn--radius-2 btn--blue-2" type="submit" name="grava" Value="Atualizar"></br></br>
                    <a href="tela_efetivo.php">Cancelar</a>
                </div>
                    </form>
                </div>          
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Jquery JS-->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <!-- Main JS-->
    <script src="js/global.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
<!-- end document-->
```

PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once('conexao.php');
            
$re = $_POST['re'];
$pg = $_POST['pg'];
$qra = $_POST['ng'];
$cia = $_POST['cia'];
$funcao = $_POST['funcao'];
$endereco = $_POST['endereco'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
$nome_completo = $_POST['nome_completo'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$dt_nasc = $_POST['dt_nasc'];
$cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
$rg = $_POST['rg'];
$cnh = $_POST['cnh'];
$obs = $_POST['obs'];
$nome_foto =$_POST['foto'];

echo $nome_foto;

//LINK MYSQLI COM BD
    $servidor = "localhost";
    $usuario = "root";
    $senha = "";
    $dbname = "db_efetivo";

// Cria Conexao BD SQL 
$conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);
// CHECA A CONEXAO COM O BANCO DE DADOS
if (!$conn) {
  die("Falha de Conexão: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "UPDATE tb_efetivo SET P_G ='$pg', QRA ='$qra', CIA ='$cia', FUNCAO ='$funcao', ENDERECO ='$endereco', TELEFONE ='$telefone', NOME_COMPLETO ='$nome_completo', EMAIL_FUNCIONAL ='$email', DATA_NASCIMENTO ='$dt_nasc', CPF ='$cpf', RG ='$rg', CNH ='$cnh', OBS ='$obs', FOTO ='$nome_foto' WHERE RE='$re'";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "<script> alert ('Dados atualizados com sucesso!'); </script>";
    echo "<script> window.location.href='index_adm.php'</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script> alert ('Erro ao gravar dados!Entre em contato com o administrador do Sistema!'); </script>";
    echo "<script> window.location.href='index_adm.php'</script>";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Você salva o nome da imagem na coluna FOTO?

Comment: Salvei sim, porem quando eu vou chamar o select atraves do GET, nao to conseguindo voltar as informacoes pro formulario referentes á imagem

Comment: Meu insert esta dando certo, no meu select de todos os funcionarios volta o ID, Nome e aparece a imagem no HTML, porem ao entrar em Atualizar dados, nao consigo recuperar os dados da foto no BD e tbm nao consigo atualizar ela

Answer (score -1):

Eu já passei por isso, vou tentar explicar qual é o problema.

O que causa esse problema é o fato de que quando você faz o update dos dados sem a imagem, você está executando seu código com a variavel de imagem `$_FILES['foto']` vazia, mas no seu exemplo, acima vejo que tenta enviar o nome da imagem novamente, para não deixar a coluna foto vazia, certo?!.

Primeiro você precisa verificar se existe `$_FILES['foto']['tmp_name']` sendo enviado, segundo você pode remover o campo com o nome da foto.

```
if(isset($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name']) and $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'] != ""){
   // Faz o upload da imagem e os dados salva no banco
}else{
   // Salva apenas o dados no banco;
   // Neste caso aqui é opcional passar o nome da foto.
   // Já que ela já vai estar salva na sua tabela então pode remover o campo com o nome
   // E remover essa coluna do seu sql
}
```

Comment: Entendi a lógica da coisa, porem nao estou entendendo como ficaria o código pra fazer esse update

Comment: Eu preciso que no momento do update, caso eu opte por substituir a foto q ta no banco, ela seja substituida, ou caso eu opte por atualizar somente os dados e a imagem permaneça a mesma, aconteça isso, entende?

Comment: "O que causa esse problema é o fato de que quando você faz o update dos dados sem a imagem, você está executando seu código com a variavel de imagem $_FILES['foto'] vazia, mas no seu exemplo, acima vejo que tenta enviar o nome da imagem novamente, para não deixar a coluna foto vazia, certo?!."

R: Eu tento fazer isso pra que na hora da substituicao a imagem continue a mesma! rsrs

Comment: É só você colocar os dados dentro do if ali em cima, no if eu estou verificando se você estava enviando a imagem para substituir e no else eu não substituo a imagem

Comment: Vou fazer o teste e ver o que acontece, jaja eu te dou um retorno!!

Comment: Na hora de eu fazer a consulta, tem alguma maneira de eu fazer o input type="file" ser preenchido com o nome do arquivo q ta salvo no banco?

Comment: Isso ajudaria o usuario do sistema a identificar se tem ou nao a foto salva

Comment: DEU CERTO GNOMO!! VLWWWWWW <3

Answer (score -2):

No seu formulário falta o atributo enctype="multipart/form-data" para avisar ao sistema que um arquivo está sendo enviado.
Seu form ficaria assim:

```
<form method="POST" action="update_efetivo_img.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Porém, existem outros tipos de dados no seu formulário, não sei se irá funcionar.